# Is there any way to make NextResponse.rewrite from the client

Tags: next.js

I've devided my `pages` folder on 2 sections:

- mobile
- desktop

And I do some rewrote on the server

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const isMobile = (userAgent: string) =>
  /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(userAgent);

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const userAgent = req.headers.get('user-agent');
  const { pathname, origin } = req.nextUrl;

  if (userAgent && !pathname.includes('favicon.ico')) {
    if (isMobile(userAgent)) {
      return NextResponse.rewrite(`${origin}/mobile${pathname}`);
    } else {
      return NextResponse.rewrite(`${origin}/desktop${pathname}`);
    }
  }
}
```

It is great , I hadnle 2 sizes - more 1280 and lower , and on those 2 I have some breakpoints.  But what is user for example switch from `<1280` to `>1280`, is there any way to detect it on client ( there is ) and rewrite it same way as on `_middleware` ?

Comment: Is the difference between the desktop and mobile pages just user interface related, i.e different layout, design etc. or there is functionality that you envision is completely different for desktop vs mobile?

Comment: yes, there is a different components , on this page , I wanted to decrese js in my code , prevent detecting by width is it desktop or mobile , and prevent conditions like {isDesktop ? : </Desktop>: </Mobile>}, if you want to propose just to make it by breakpoints in css , or by conditions described , is doesn't fit , I want to detect is it changed from mobile to desktop, and if so , rewrite it same way as on server , but I'm not sure it is even possible @Ramakay

Comment: Understood, I am proposing an answer below - to your point, none of them seem very clean.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this might be to use an observer that reports changes at an app level ( this kind of avoids the isDesktop like logic) - it unfortunately is doing isDesktop like logic but works more at a observer level.

i.e

```
// Modified from package example. 

import { Observe } from '@envato/react-breakpoints';

const exampleBreakpoints = {
    widths: {
      0: 'mobile',
      769: 'tablet',
      1280: 'desktop',

    }
  };

export const ExampleComponent = () => (
  <Observe breakpoints={exampleBreakpoints}>
    {({ observedElementProps, widthMatch = 'ssr' }) => (
      <div {...observedElementProps}>
        <div className={widthMatch}>
     <YourComponent />
      </div>
    )}
  </Observe>
);
```

https://github.com/envato/react-breakpoints

The interesting thing about this package is on the server, you will get undefined, see https://github.com/envato/react-breakpoints/blob/main/docs/server-side-rendering.md

Instead of doing user agent matching, you can reflect where the changes are happening, this means you can do SSR accordingly like you were doing.

I see the flow happening like below:

1. User loads a page on Desktop - SSR gets undefined from   so renders a Desktop page
2. User resizes, `ResizeObserverProvider` will trigger and since its a provider, it will cascade the props to children who can use it.

This is one of the many ways to do it but it involves client side calculations.